# checking different conditions in where clause got error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the column values form different tables included in below query but when i am checking diferent conditions in where clause it gives error.

```
                                  sql = @"SELECT members.member_Id, members.member_Lastname, members.member_Firstname, members.member_PostCode";
  sql += "," + "members.member_Reference,  members.member_Dob, members.member_IsBiometric, mshiptypes.mshipType_Name, mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Name";
  sql += "," + "membertomships.memberToMship_EndDate";
  sql += " "+"FROM members LEFT JOIN membertomships ON membertomships.member_Id = members.member_Id";
  sql += " "+"LEFT JOIN mshipstatustypes ON mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id = membertomships.mshipStatusType_Id";
  sql += " "+"LEFT JOIN mshipoptions ON mshipoptions.mshipOption_Id = membertomships.mshipOption_Id";
  sql += " "+"LEFT JOIN mshiptypes ON mshiptypes.mshipType_Id = mshipoptions.mshipType_Id";
  sql += " " + "WHERE memberToMship_PayMethod='Cash' AND  mshipStausType_Name ='Live' AND  mshipStatusType_Name = 'Defaulter'  AND mshipStatusType_Name='Frozen'";
```

but it was giving error like this

```
                          Error Code: 1054
                          Unknown column 'mshipStausType_Name' in 'where clause'
```

can any one help me on this   i am using mysql...

this si the modified query but it does not pull ant data it was giving empty column values

```
                                              sql = @"SELECT members.member_Id, members.member_Lastname, members.member_Firstname, members.member_PostCode";
  sql += "," + "members.member_Reference,  members.member_Dob, members.member_IsBiometric, mshiptypes.mshipType_Name, mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Name";
  sql += "," + "membertomships.memberToMship_EndDate";
  sql += " "+"FROM members LEFT JOIN membertomships ON membertomships.member_Id = members.member_Id";
  sql += " "+"LEFT JOIN mshipstatustypes ON mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id = membertomships.mshipStatusType_Id";
  sql += " "+"LEFT JOIN mshipoptions ON mshipoptions.mshipOption_Id = membertomships.mshipOption_Id";
  sql += " "+"LEFT JOIN mshiptypes ON mshiptypes.mshipType_Id = mshipoptions.mshipType_Id";
  sql += " " + "WHERE membertomships.memberToMship_PayMethod='Cash' AND  mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Name='Live' AND  mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Name = 'Defaulter'  AND mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Name='Frozen'"
```

Comment: Spelling mistake? It looks like it should be mshipStatusType_Name instead of mshipStausType_Name

Comment: That indicates that in the tables you have used in your query you dont have that column. Check if you have spelled the column name correctly or if you have included the table with that column.

Comment: `mshipStausType_Name ='Live' AND  mshipStatusType_Name = 'Defaulter'  AND mshipStatusType_Name='Frozen'` will never be true for any row of the table. Perhaps (after fixing column names) you want to bracket these 3 comparisons, and change `AND` to `OR`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if spelling of the column is right then i think compiler dont identified that the column belongs to which table as column appears in multiple tables so try to use table name before column like

```
mshiptypes.mshipType_Name
```

There is no possibility that there is two values in mshipStatusType_Name at a time you use OR
instead of And Like this:

```
mshipStatusType_Name='value1' or mshipStatusType_Name='value2' ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this has been commented, I'll post an answer.  The error is from the fact that the table your `where` is acting on does not contain the `mshipStausType_Name` column.  As commented, and looking at your SQL, there is a reference to `mshipStatusType_Name` so I'd also assume a spelling mistake.

Comment: there must be a members who has mshipStausType_Name  is default  and live but it does not pull the member record....is that query checking is correct.....